# Usar cláusula DISTINCT SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, distinct

Olá, Preciso de uma ajuda !
Preciso fazer uma query e trazer os NIF's, sem repetir.
Faço isso assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NIF FROM CustomerRegistrations
```

Mas quero trazer também mais colunas dessa tabela. Mas não posso fazer isso:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NIF, Name, RegistrationDate FROM CustomerRegistrations
```

Porque vai trazer NIF's repetidos. Ou seja, há NIF's com nomes diferentes, mas só quero trazer um.
Obrigado a quem ajudar !

Comment: Se alguma das outras colunas conter dados diferentes terão que repetir mesmo, até porque os dados são diferentes comparando-se a linha.

Comment: @Marconi pois eu entendo, eu queria saber se havia possibilidade de fazer o que estava a perguntar mas pelos vistos não.

Comment: Se você adicionar a estrutura da sua tabela com alguns dados e explicar o que quer que saia no resultado tento ajudar em uma solução @DC =D

Comment: @Marconi Já encontrei outra solução, muito obrigado pela disponibilidade !!

Comment: @DC, compartilhe essa solução como uma resposta com a gente

Answer (score 1):

[select distinct em tabela temporaria sql server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334371/select-distinct-em-tabela-temporaria-sql-server)

Basicamente é o mesmo problema que eu tive:
o autor desse código é [@joséDiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57789/jos%C3%A9-diz), vou modificar ele pra atender a sua demanda:

```
WITH Sinc_2
AS (SELECT*,
        seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NIF ORDER BY NIF)
        FROM CustomerRegistrations)
SELECT nomerepresentante, codigorepresentante, datasinc
FROM Sinc_2
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Quanto mais colunas você colocar em `PARTITION BY`, menos distinção ele fará