# select distinct em tabela temporaria sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, order-by, distinct

Tenho o seguinte código:
*(é de uma tabela que os representantes possuem o mesmo código, o que gera valores duplicados, resolvo isso pegando o representante mais atual, em resumo o ultimo cara que sincronizou)*

```
select distinct top $numeroRepresentantes
    t.nomerepresentante,
    t.codigorepresentante 
    from (SELECT distinct
                s.nomeRepresentante,
                s.codigorepresentante,
                datasinc
                FROM vw_Sincronismo s 
                where s.CodigoRepresentante in(102,120) 
                ORDER BY s.datasinc desc) as t
```

Que me retorna o seguinte erro:

> *Mensagem 1033, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 5 
>  A cláusula ORDER BY é inválida em exibições, funções embutidas, tabelas derivadas,
>   subconsultas e expressões de tabela comuns, a menos que TOP, OFFSET ou
>   FOR XML também esteja especificado.*

Desculpem a ignorância eu não entendo muito de SQL, mas preciso que todos os resultados da tabela apareçam, se necessário, não posso usar um **TOP** *numerogrande* para resolver os meus problemas, gostaria de entender o que houve aqui

Comment: Sobre "_o ultimo cara que sincronizou_", necessita do último sincronismo de cada representante OU o último sincronismo, seja qual for o representante?

Comment: eu uso o ultimo sincronismo pra garantir que ele é o "dono atual" do _codigoRepresentante_ atribuído a ele, outros representantes com o mesmo código, eu assumo como "demitidos"

Comment: Compreendi sobre a reutilização de códigos; inclusive alterei o código #1 para obter somente a última sincronização de cada valor de  `CodigoRepresentante` . A dúvida agora é: o que a consulta deve retornar?

Comment: @JoséDiz, exatamente isso, o ultimo representante com o código x, eu estava estudando seu código e já havia feito essa alteração que você acabou implementando no v2, então apenas a marquei como resposta correta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *os representantes possuem o mesmo código (...)
>
>   pegando o representante mais atual, em resumo o ultimo cara que sincronizou*

Se o que necessita é o último sincronismo de cada representante, verifique se o código seguinte atende ao que necessita.

```
-- código #1 v2
with Sinc_2 as (
SELECT *, 
       seq= row_number() over (partition by CodigoRepresentante
                               order by datasinc desc)
  from vw_Sincronismo
  --where CodigoRepresentante in (102, 120)
)
SELECT nomerepresentante, codigorepresentante, datasinc 
  from Sinc_2
  where seq = 1;
```

O código acima utiliza CTE (*common table expression*), que facilita a compreensão e manutenção do mesmo. Vide artigo “[Programação modular com expressões de tabela (CTE)](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/09/23/programacao-modular-com-expressoes-de-tabela-cte/)”.